# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () - Spring MVC - Static Resources

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I having an issue for get static resources in my jsp. I think my java configuration is well and i tried many solution for fix this problem but 
I didn't succeed.

Here, the dispatcher :

```
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/").setCachePeriod(3600)
        .resourceChain(true).addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver jspViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
    public CommonsMultipartResolver getMultipartResolver() {
        return new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    }

    @Bean(name = "messageSource")
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource getMessageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource resource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        resource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
        resource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return resource;
    }
```

Here web.xml

```
public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {

    // Create the 'root' Spring application context
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    rootContext.register(ServiceConf.class, PersistenceConf.class, DaoConf.class);

    // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
    container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

    // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherServlet = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    dispatcherServlet.register(AppMvcConf.class);

    // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherServlet));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/");

}[
```

Here the hierarchy where is my image:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZqMy.png)

Call in my jsp :

```html
                   <c:otherwise>
      
      </c:otherwise>
     </c:choose>
     <img alt="img" src='<c:url value = "/resources/logo.jpg"></c:url>' />
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

When i launch Tomcat, all display correctly but not image, the link generate in "Developper Tool" when i see in console is :

```html
<img src="myApp/resources/logo.jpg"/>
```

Can you help me to resolve this problem ? because i don't unknown the cause after several attempts for resolve it

Thank you

Comment: Try this - <img alt="img" src='<c:url value = "logo.jpg"></c:url>' />

Comment: i have the same issue with line of code

Comment: I Resolved the issue  when i removed the annotation 
@EnableWebMvc. Refer this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44567155/no-mapping-found-for-http-request-with-uri-css-school-style-css-in-dispatcher