# Spring failing to find static resource mapped by ResourceHandler

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am attempting to configure my Spring Boot MVC application to serve some audio files under `static\recordings` in my `resources` directory.

I've added the following mapping

```
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/recordings/**.wav", "/recordings/**.mp3").addResourceLocations("/static/recordings/");
}
```

However, requesting either:

```
/recordings/general/en/en-general-choose-language.wav
static/recordings/general/en/en-general-choose-language.wav
```

Gives a 404, with this in the logs (adjusted slightly based on path, of course):

```
Looking up handler method for path /recordings/general/en/en-general-choose-language.wav
Did not find handler method for [/recordings/general/en/en-general-choose-language.wav]
```

I have a work-around with a Controller and writing the file contents to the response stream but it seems silly to have to do that to serve a static file.

Comment: Can you try `public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
          .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
          .addResourceLocations("/resources/"); 
    }` in your config class?

Comment: If you are using springboot, then you can set `spring.resources.static-locations`

Comment: Try to read about how to serve static content with Spring boot, here's one of my posts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41057042/spring-boot-css-showing-up-blank-not-loading-after-trying-everything/41058923#41058923

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of ResourceHandlerRegistry#addResourceHandler states the following: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/ResourceHandlerRegistry.html#addResourceHandler-java.lang.String...-

> Patterns like "/static/**" or "/css/{filename:\w+\.css}" are allowed. See AntPathMatcher for more details on the syntax.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html

In the description of AntPathMatcher we find an example matching your needs:

> org/springframework/**/*.jsp — matches all .jsp files underneath the org/springframework path

Hence, try `"/recordings/**/*.wav"` as the handler pattern.